# Cannot install Pear Package HTML_BBCodeParser2(beta) on my system

Tags: php, ubuntu, download, package, pear

I've tried the following things:

> sudo pear install -f HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0

Result:

> downloading HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz ...
>   Starting to download HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz (14,621 bytes)
>   .....done: 14,621 bytes
>   could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/php5-8gpaOy/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz"
>   Download of "pear/HTML_BBCodeParser2" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
>   Error: cannot download "pear/HTML_BBCodeParser2"
>   Download failed
>   install failed

Then:

> sudo pear install HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0
>
> Starting to download HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz (14,621 bytes)
>   .....done: 14,621 bytes
>   could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/php5-8gpaOy/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz"
>   Download of "pear/HTML_BBCodeParser2" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
>   Error: cannot download "pear/HTML_BBCodeParser2"
>   Download failed
>   install failed

Then:

> sudo pear install HTML_BBCodeParser2-beta
>
> downloading HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz ...
>   Starting to download HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz (14,621 bytes)
>   .....done: 14,621 bytes
>   could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/php5-8gpaOy/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0.tgz"
>   Download of "pear/HTML_BBCodeParser2" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
>   Error: cannot download "pear/HTML_BBCodeParser2"
>   Download failed
>   install failed

I'm running out of tricks and reasoning... Please help. Can't figure out the problem and so can't solve it. Help! I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This question is on the 'ask-ubuntu' forum too but no responses...
Someone with rep more than 300 please edit the question and add a 'pear' tag. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, whenever ubuntu/debian push out an update that touches on PEAR, they revert the installed version of Archive_Tar to a broken one.
I've reported this several times.

You need to upgrade Archive_Tar to a version that works. Do this with:

```
$ sudo pear upgrade -Z pear/Archive_Tar
```

After that you should be able to install HTML_BBCodeParser2 just fine.

(I would also recommend that you upgrade to PEAR 1.10.0)